# Order DataFrame in R keeping a pattern

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
      TISSUE TREATMENT TIME CONTROL
1     Seed        GR   24       0
2     Seed        GR    6       0
3     Seed      KAR1   24       0
4     Seed      KAR1    6       0
5 Seedling        GR   24       0
6 Seedling        GR    6       0
7 Seedling      KAR1   24       0
8 Seedling      KAR1    6       0
```

I need to reorder it so that the TIME is NOT! 24, 6, 24, 6, 24, 6, 24, 6 but 6, 24, 6, 24, 6, 24, 6, 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
df[order(df$TISSUE, df$TREATMENT, df$TIME),] #first order on TISSUE, than on TREATMENT and finally on TIME.

df

    TISSUE TREATMENT TIME CONTROL
2     Seed        GR    6       0
1     Seed        GR   24       0
4     Seed      KAR1    6       0
3     Seed      KAR1   24       0
6 Seedling        GR    6       0
5 Seedling        GR   24       0
8 Seedling      KAR1    6       0
7 Seedling      KAR1   24       0
```

DATA:

```
df <- read.table(text = "
TISSUE TREATMENT TIME CONTROL
1     Seed        GR   24       0
2     Seed        GR    6       0
3     Seed      KAR1   24       0
4     Seed      KAR1    6       0
5 Seedling        GR   24       0
6 Seedling        GR    6       0
7 Seedling      KAR1   24       0
8 Seedling      KAR1    6       0", h = T)
```

Just to add a `tidyverse` answer:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  arrange(TISSUE, TREATMENT, TIME)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what i need.